# How to get waitbar on top of other figures?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Hi i am using waitbar in a script `readAndInitDatabase()` which as the name implies reads and initializes image database for further processing.

The problem is this i have used imshow() in this function that is used for displaying the image which is being read, this cause the waitbar to hide behind the figure how can i cause not to let this happen?

I have tried to use set command to set the position of the bar at every iteration but this completely changes the size which i don't want. This is the code for setting the position

```
parentFolder = ['E:\' ...
               'Hand-Gesture\Project\Project_0\' ...
               'Images\Database'];
parentFolder = strcat(parentFolder(1:end));
chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
h = waitbar(0,'Reading Database Images');
for i = 1:length(chars)
    letter = chars(i);
    folder = strcat(parentFolder,'\',letter);
    read_folder(folder);
    waitbar(i/length(chars));
    % this code sets the position of waitbar at every iteration 
    screenSize = get(0,'ScreenSize');
    pointsPerPixel = 72/get(0,'ScreenPixelsPerInch');
    width = 360 * pointsPerPixel;
    height = 75 * pointsPerPixel;
    pos = [screenSize(3)/2-width/2 screenSize(4)/2-height/2 width height];   
    set(h,'Position',pos);
end
close(h);
```

How do i do this? I want to avoid the set() command if i can, to do this task.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
h = waitbar(0,'Reading Database Images','WindowStyle','modal');
```

Setting the [figure property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure_props.html) window style to 'modal' keeps the figure in the foreground and eliminates the menu bar (which is already absent in the waitbar anyway).